# Vue.js transition-group *-move class not added

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm learning Vue and am not sure if I am missing something fundamental or this is a bug. I read https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions many times and it seems to me that the first example ought to be analogous to my test.

Usage: click the bars.
I would expect the *-move class to be added to the elements in this situation, but it is not.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adarkar/unwgzt87/

HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<svg id="svg" width="200" height="200">
  <g transform="translate(0,200) scale(1,-1)">
  <transition-group appear name="anim" tag="g">
  <rect v-for="(x,i) in xs" :key="x"
    :x="50*i" y="0" width="30" :height="50*x"
    style="fill: crimson;" @click="vue.xs.reverse()"></rect>
  </transition-group>
  </g>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.anim-move { transition: x 2s; }
```

Js:

```
var vue = new Vue({
  el: "#svg",
  data: { xs: [1,2,3] }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `transition` CSS property takes another CSS **properties** to transition to/from, not really an element attribute (FYI, [`x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/x) is actually an SVG **attribute**). If you take a closer look at [the example you posted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions), it's actually transitioning a `transform` property.

Now, since you seem to want to use the [shorthand of the `transition` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#Defining_transitions), here's the correct syntax for it:

```css
div {
  transition: <property> <duration> <timing-function> <delay>;
}
```

#### Working example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#svg",
  data: () => ({
    xs: [1, 2, 3]
  })
});
```

```css
.anim-move {
  transition: transform 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<svg id="svg" width="200" height="200">
  <g transform="translate(0,200) scale(1,-1)">
  <transition-group appear name="anim" tag="g">
    <rect v-for="(x,i) in xs" :key="x"
      :x="50*i" y="0" width="30" :height="50*x"
      style="fill: crimson;" @click="xs.reverse()">
    </rect>
  </transition-group>
  </g>
</svg>
```

To set multiple CSS properties to which the `transition` effect should be applied, consider using the [`transition-property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property) instead.

Comment: Well this was what I had actually started with, but by earlier tests I concluded that the `transform` was not going to work in this case and changed it to `x` (which anyway seems to work as a transition target in other scenarios even if not being a css property), then forgetting this point when minimizing the example. Thanks! Anyway